# Built-in LED turns on when I touch the input port

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm a beginner. I bought a new Arduino and I uploaded the basic example button code.

```
const int buttonPin = 2;     
const int ledPin =  13;      
int buttonState = 0;         

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

But the problem is that when I touch port 2 the output is getting so I changed the port number 2 to 3 even though without any supply the output is getting on.

Give me some suggestion.

Comment: Try `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP)` and `if (buttonState == LOW)...`. An input pin that is not connected is floating and touching it may give enough voltage to make it go HIGH.

Comment: Follow the basic Button tutorial: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button

Comment: That's is to be expected if you leave the input **floating**.

Answer (score 2):

When you are reading digital data through a pin you must make sure that you are steering that input pin to a stable state when no input is present. 
You can do this by using either a pullup or a pulldown resistor which you can connect externally or you can use the in built pullup. 
You can use a 10k ohm resistor to pulldown by connecting it to the button end where your digital pin is connected and the other to ground.
By doing this your above code must work fine.
I think by touching the pin you are actually pulling the voltage state down.
Hope this helps